# ggpolot2 Scale_x_log10() transform doesn't show ticks and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using NHANES package from R and trying to see the relationship between BMI and average systolic blood pressure for men and women. 
I plotted a scatter plot, and because the data is concentrated on the lower-left corner, I did log-transformation of the BMI variable (I know both variables need transformation, but for the time being I am interested in transforming the BMI only). However, after the transformation, the BMI doesn't have any ticks and labels.

```
library(NHANES)
bp.bmi = NHANES[ ,c("BPSysAve", "BMI", "Gender")]

ggplot(bp.bmi, aes(x = BMI, y = BPSysAve, color = Gender)) +
  geom_point(alpha=5/20) + 
  scale_x_log10()    # gave no ticks and labels in the x axis
```

[image]

Then, I maually added breaks = c(0,20,40,60,80) inside the scale_x_log10, but the grid looks un equal and wierd.

```
ggplot(bp.bmi, aes(x = BMI, y = BPSysAve, color = Gender)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=5/20) + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0,20,40,60,80))    # gave un equal size gird.
```

I expect the output of the code to be a plot with ticks and labels. How can I achieve a plot with ticks and labels as the original plot?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the first code comment: *gave no ticks and labels in the x axis*. As for the second, try `breaks = c(0, 20, 40, 80)`.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the no ticks and no labels. You could try `ggplot(bp.bmi, aes(x = BMI, y = BPSysAve, color = Gender)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=5/20) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", breaks = c(20, 40, 80))`

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks for taking time to help. I edited the post and attached a picture. I thought it automatically gives a label without specifying the break.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks. So, is it a must to specify the breaks if I use the scale_x_log10()?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to automatically label and when I use your exact code I get reasonable labels and tickmarks at 20, 30 and 50. Are you sure there isn't an interfering package or that this is a version issue? Does this still happen if you open up a clean session?

Comment: @teunbrand yes I opened a new r markdown and the result is the same, but when I specify the breaks = c(20, 40, 80) it works fine.

Comment: Please tell us the version of R and ggplot2 you are using.

Comment: @ErichNeuwirth I am using R version 3.4.2 and ggplot2 version 2.2.1.

Comment: Can you update to a current version of ggplot2? ggplot2 3.1.1 should be available for your version of R.

Comment: @ErichNeuwirth I did and it's working fine now. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and got the two enclosed charts. So I did not see your problem and misunderstood what you are asking for.
It might be a version problem.
I am using R 3.6.0 and ggplot2 3.1.1.9000 (from github)

[image]